# IP of Server using Tor and pycurl

Tags: python, curl, tor, pycurl

I am working on a project using tor and python, for which I have to get the server ip of the given url using pycurl.

Currently I am using the following code for simple query and response.

```
def query(url):
  """
  Uses pycurl to fetch a site using the proxy on the SOCKS_PORT.
  """
  output = StringIO.StringIO()

  curl = pycurl.Curl()
  curl.setopt( pycurl.URL, url )
  curl.setopt( pycurl.PROXY, '188.120.228.106' )
  curl.setopt( pycurl.PROXYPORT, 1080 )
  curl.setopt( pycurl.PROXYTYPE, pycurl.PROXYTYPE_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME )
  curl.setopt(pycurl.CONNECTTIMEOUT, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT)

  try:
    curl.perform()
    return output.getvalue()
  except pycurl.error as exc:
    raise ValueError("Unable to reach %s (%s)" % (url, exc))
```

Any suggestion on how to change the code so that I can also get the server IP of the given url.

Comment: You're using a proxy, you don't know the IP of the remote server.

Comment: Since you're connecting through a proxy, cURL will only know the proxy server IP as Daniel said.  To get the server IP, you just need to do a DNS lookup of the URL's hostname.  You can do this in Python using the computer's DNS resolver, or resolve it over Tor by connecting to Tor's control port and issuing a [RESOLVE](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/control-spec.txt) command (see section 3.20).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the correct flag you're looking for is [`CURLINFO_PRIMARY_IP`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html).

Try using `curl.getinfo(pycurl.PRIMARY_IP)` on your `pycurl.Curl()` object.